# SailsJS pass data to view - undefined

Tags: sails.js

I'm playing about with SailsJS and I've got the following view:

```
<p>Products <%= category %></p>
```

With the following Controller:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(req, res) {
        res.view('pages/products', {
            category: req.params.category
        });
    }
};
```

And the route:

```
  '/products/:category': 'ProductsController.get',
```

When navigating to this *really* simple setup, I get the following:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 ReferenceError: /var/www/html/curioushaven/views/pages/products.ejs:1
 >> 1| <p>Products <%= category %></p>
    2|

category is not defined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:237:14), <anonymous>:30:54)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:237:14), <anonymous>:30:80)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:250:15
    at Object.exports.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:288:13)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:318:20)
    at SailsView.module.exports [as engine] (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:85:7)
    at SailsView.View.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8)
    at Function.app.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:561:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:845:7)
    at ServerResponse.res.view (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/res.view.js:284:16)
    at Object.module.exports.get (/var/www/html/curioushaven/api/controllers/ProductsController.js:10:7)
    at wrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3095:19)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)
    at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
    at param (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
    at param (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
    at nextRoute (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)
    at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)
    at alwaysAllow (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:224:11)
    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)
    at callbacks (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**Edit** - I should point out that I've tried varying forms of `req.param('category')` and `req.params.category` etc etc...

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem with the code you provided -- it looks a-ok to me.  What version of Sails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using

```
req.param('category')
```

this

```
req.params.id
```

should fix your problem. However `req.param('category')` should work as well and from your code I cannot see why it should not work.

Comment: Sorry. Copy paste error. It's category throughout now. I changed it in case type was reserved and hadn't seen, and it was getting overwritten. I'll edit.